# Java - JRadioButton isSelected

Tags: java, swing

I have simple check like this:

```
boolean isPressed;


 if ((jRadioButton1.isSelected() == false) || (jRadioButton2.isSelected() == false) || (jRadioButton3.isSelected() == false)) {
        isPressed = false;
    } else {
        isPressed = true;
    }
    System.out.println(isPressed);
```

Why I always get false, even if I mark RadioButton in panel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic implies that if either of your radio buttons isn't pressed then isPressed is false.

Try switching the logic around

```
if ((jRadioButton1.isSelected() == true) || (jRadioButton2.isSelected() == true) || (jRadioButton3.isSelected() == true)) {
    isPressed = true;
} else {
    isPressed = false;
}
System.out.println(isPressed);
```

EDIT: Can be simplified to

```
isPressed = (jRadioButton1.isSelected() || jRadioButton2.isSelected() || jRadioButton3.isSelected())
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use and (&&) instead of or (||) in your if clause.

```
if ((jRadioButton1.isSelected() == false) &&
      (jRadioButton2.isSelected() == false) && 
      (jRadioButton3.isSelected() == false)) {
        isPressed = false;
    } else {
        isPressed = true;
    }
    System.out.println(isPressed);
```